# Proving inequality $\frac{1}{2}e^x\left(2+e^x\right) > \left(1+e^x\right)\ln(1+e^x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Do you have any ideas on how to show the following inequality?

$$\frac{1}{2}e^x\left(2+e^x\right) > \left(1+e^x\right)\ln(1+e^x)$$

It's not about the convexity of any of those functions. Derivatives doesn't look interesting to me as well, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Substituting $t = e^x + 1$ looks promising.

Comment: The interesting area is $x$ large and negative. Then it is only just true. For positive $x$ it is obviously true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By following @Daniel Fischer's suggestion, we only need to prove that:
$$\frac{t^2-1}{2t}>\log t\tag{1}$$
for any $t>1$. By replacing $t$ with $e^u$, we only need to prove that:
$$ u < \sinh u \tag{2}$$
for any $u>0$. But $(2)$ is trivial by convexity, since $\sinh 0=0$, $\sinh' 0 = \cosh 0 = 1$ and $\sinh'' u=\sinh u > 0$ for any $u>0$.